# Should we train calves 3 times per week?

Tags: training, calf

Once i heard, that a our calves have fast recovery time! And they are "*hard*" to grow, so some professionals defend the ideia of training it **3 times per week**, what do you think? Someone have another method for calf training?

Comment: http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/most_recent/the_answer_for_massive_calves This is an article that can shed some light on your question. I didnt read thru the entire thing which is why I am posting it as a comment. The little that I did read seems to really be applicable and helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

Calf are a small enough muscle group that no matter how many times you work them you are not going to run into over training issue by working them.  So work them as much as you want.

I think the question that you want to ask is.

I’m a novice lifter and I want bigger calves.  Should I work my calves 3 times a week?

Can’t hurt might not help.  It might sound like rhetoric but the squat is king.  Squat heavy ass weights, sleep plenty as night and eat a calorie surplus.

Comment: I don't see how squats would exercise the calves in a significant way.  The calf muscles are responsible for plantarflexion of the foot, so exercises that involve pushing the toes against a surface, away from the body, will engage calves.  Unless you're doing some kind of strange tiptoe squat I've never heard of, squats won't cause a contraction of the calves because the heels are anchored to the ground.  Jumping is a good plyometric movement for calves; calf presses on a leg press machine also work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of those questions that must be addressed individually.  Most people who weight train have a body part that does not respond to training as effectively as other body parts.  Given that, you should adjust your training to accommodate those types of body parts.  I, for one, get plenty of indirect work on my calves through other leg work.  This allows me to work calves twice per week.